# Linux, make shorcut keys and FN key always active

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, gnome, fullscreen

If I play full a screen game under Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 using GNOME Shell 3.4) I can not use some of my <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys, nor the GNOME Shell shortcuts.

For example the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+volume, or brightness doesn't work, but the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+wireless does.

Does anybody know how to make those keys works no matter what application I start?

Answer (score 0):

i think, this problem came from the hotkey driver. just try to update your repository,

i ever got same problem with you, and it resolved when i update my repository:

try it:

```
# apt-get update
```

and viola :)

Comment: thanks, but it didn't help, also, this would only fix the FN+something problem, but I can't even use ALT+Tab to switch between windows. It works normally, and if the games isn't fullscreened but it doesn't if they are.